# How can I move to an anchor on a page when I'm using Sammy.js?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, sammy.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

I'm using Sammy.js, and it handles all the client-side URL navigation. I want to navigate to `/page#fragment`, but the page wont actually go to `#fragment`. How can I make it do that, either automatically, or by writing code to go to the fragment?

Comment: not a duplicate - this question is specifically about sammy.js

Comment: definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Sammy doesnt automatically trigger the route, so in your handler you need to add:

```
hash = window.location.hash
if(hash != '') { 
    window.location.hash = hash;
}
```