# spring tiles and #

Tags: java, jquery, spring, tabs, tiles

I have a Spring-based java project. At frontend I have jQuery. The main jQuery compoinent is Tabs, so access to my main page can be `http://myIp/project/myController#Tab1`

I need to ways to go to this page:

- via redirect:   redirect:/myController#Tab1  (and this case works)
- [when validation fails] I need to pass them back via `return
  "adminOperations#Tab1"` (and this case doesn't work)

Definition of 'adminOperations':

```
<definition name="adminOperations" extends=".mainTemplate" >
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Admin page" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/admin.jsp" />
    <put-list-attribute name="scripts" inherit="true">
        <add-attribute value="admin.js" type="string" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

Template Page content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>

    <tiles:useAttribute id="scripts" name="scripts" classname="java.util.List" />
    <!-- processing script & styles data -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerTitle"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to implement correct processing of '#' symbol in this tiles?

Comment: ue question is bit unclear..you should post ur controller file as well as admin.jsp .

    via redirect: redirect:/myController#Tab1 (and this case works)

    [when validation fails] I need to pass them back via return "adminOperations#Tab1" (and this case doesn't work){which validation?} .Post the admin.js file as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is purely a browser thing. When you send a request to a URL like `/foo.action#bar`, the browser sends a request to `/foo.action`, renders the HTML from the response, then finds an anchor with the `bar` name or ID in the HTML, and scrolls to this anchor. If you send a request to `/foo.action` (when submitting your form), there is no way for the server to change the URL the browser sent a request to and to tell it to go to the `bar` anchor.

The only way is to generate an HTML page containing a JavaScript function called when the page is loaded and jumping to the bar anchor. See [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript) for how to do that.

Comment: But I need to pass a parameter - anchor from java part ... How can I do that?

Comment: Generate the appropriate JavaScript, just like you would generate appropriate HTML.