# How i can scroll page down/up with animation in html

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to make simple website look like http://dipstrategy.com/

What i can do is jump to the specified page using a href.

But i want to make it scroll down, not jump into the specified page.
Can anyone have suggestion?
Thanks, regards rudy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="#hello">hello</a>` will go to the top of `<div id="hello">...</div>`.

For smooth scrolling using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash, $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

(from [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery)). `900` means 900 ms here. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHS6b/).

Comment: to use that jquery what i must do? where i need to paste that code?

Comment: I think you need a little bit more experience with JavaScript (and jQuery). Go to [jQuery's official website](http://jquery.com/) and do a few tutorials.

Comment: iam already paste it beetween body, but the jquery didn't working.
any other step i need to do?

Comment: Yes: [include jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery).

Comment: or i need to paste it into separate .js file?

Comment: ok i got it dude.. Thanks a lot for your help..
And the last how to make the navigarion bar (in the top) become static, not dynamic?
like in http://dipstrategy.com/

Answer (score 0):

This method uses linking within a page. Basically in their nav links they have used an ID to somewhere down their page. Within CSS, they have then added and ease-in-out affect to smooth the transition.

More info can be found here: http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Comment: Here is more information if you need it as well: http://www.wikihow.com/Link-Within-a-Page-Using-HTML

Comment: thx dude, iam using jquery for smooth scroll..

Answer (score 0):

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html)

```
     <div id="#home">content</div>
     <div id="#do">content</div>
     <div id="#team">content</div>
     <div id="#work">content</div>
     <div id="#contact">content</div>
```

In menu

```
 <div class="navigation ">
            <ul id="nav">
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#do">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#team">CORE TEAM</a></li>
            <li class="margin-right15"><a href="#work">WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```