# scroll data content of a tab into view using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab which toggles data. But in mobile devices, i need to scroll the page to view when clicking the tabs. Here is the code I am using.

```
<div class="tabbable span3" id="tab-switch">

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li class="active"> <a href="#ppt" data-toggle="tab"><h3>PPT</h3></a></li>
<li> <a href="#qb" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Question Bank</h3></a></li>
<li> <a href="#lp" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Lesson Plan</h3></a></li>     
<li> <a href="#vid" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Videos</h3></a></li> 
<li> <a href="#ask" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Ask A Question</h3></a></li>   
</ul>    
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use jQuerys .animate(), .offset() and scrollTop. Like

```
$(document.body).animate({
'scrollTop':   $('#anchorName2').offset().top
}, 2000)
```

Check this answer

[How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)