# how to visit my site by .xyz.com/#divname, can any one help me?

Tags: javascript, html

I want browse directly to my site div by this way:

```
www.xyz.com/#divname
```

some sites I saw , I know there is a way to do it ,can anyone tell me the code

I have tried

```
window.location.href=#divname
```

but not scrolling.

Comment: Your `div` should have an `id` that matches. Try it, and come back if you get stuck with something more specific - and include your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
<body onload="window.location.hash = '#divname';">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.location.hash = '#divname';
```

Where `#divname` is the `id` of your `div`

Comment: I've tried this method and found in Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63) that the `location.hash` only works once. E.g. If a user is scrolled to an anchor then moves away and wants to be scrolled back to the same anchor it doesn't work. `location.href` seems to work always. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmhN5/1/), I don't know if the same happens on other browsers.

Comment: @AeroX this is a solution for you http://jsfiddle.net/cmhN5/3/. Just add an anchor that is not used `location.hash = 'anchornotused';`

Answer (score 1):

That is called bookmark links, see here http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/bookmark.php.

To navigate to an anchor via javascript you can use this code:

```
window.location.hash = "#divname";
```

This topic is also a duplicate of the following:
[How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to browse directly using a URL (as per your question), then there is absolutely no need for any javascript.

All you need to do is set an `id` for your `div` elements, that match the anchor tag you want to use. In the case of your example:

> www.xyz.com/#divname

Then you would need an element like so:

```
<div id="divname">
</div>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LycaS/)