# How to set starting point for a webpage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is that how to set a starting point for a webpage when it is loaded. I have some information in a content placeholder, when the form containing the content placeholder is loaded instead of displaying the information in the content placeholder it goes back to the top and i have to scroll down every time. Is there any way i can make the content place holder  as the starting display point for my webpage?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using asp.net web forms, you can use below snippet to set the focus on your placeholder/server control,

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Page.SetFocus(ContentPlaceHolderID);
}
```

Comment: That's a good point.  OP doesn't really say if it's web forms, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Pages.

Comment: It doesn't work... setfocus is not working on Content placeholder control

Answer (score 0):

Add an HTML anchor in the view where the you want to be scrolled down to.   Then on page load use java script to move to the anchor.   see [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Here is an example assuming you are using Razor with a section render

```
<a href="#contentAnchor">
   @RenderSection("content")
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         location.hash = "#contentAnchor";
     });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to use Javascript. You can just open the page at the anchor using URL#anchorName. Define the anchor like this: <a name="anchorName" />

Comment: That's if he has control over the page request.  Seems like he just has the URL and wants to move it programmatically to an anchor spot.  He could do Request.Redirect to the hash but that would cause two web request hits.