# Automatically scroll to a div when Flask returns rendered template

Tags: python, flask

I want to scroll to a specific div on the rendered template.  I know I can add an anchor like `#something`, but I'm rendering the template, I can't change the url.  How can I do this?

```html
<div id="something">...</div>
```

```
def search():
    ...
    return render_template('search.html')  # should scroll to #something
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do anything on the response from the server, but you can add a small JavaScript snippet on the rendered template that will scroll the page to where you want.  See [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) or [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

```
# pass scroll if you want to scroll somewhere
return render_template('search.html', scroll='something')
```

```html
<div id="something">
{% if scroll %}
<script>
    document.getElementById('{{ scroll }}').scrollIntoView();
    // or
    document.location.hash = '#' + '{{ scroll }}';
</script>
{% endif %}
```

See [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript) for more information.

If you're redirecting, so you can control the URL, see [Link to a specific location in a Flask template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843675/link-to-a-specific-location-in-a-flask-template).