# Link to a specific location in a Flask template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In HTML I can link directly to a specific location on a page, assuming there's an element with the given id:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/stuff.html#exactlocation">Go there</a>
```

In Flask I tried to add the anchor to `render_template` but I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: stuff.html#exactlocation`.

```
@main.route('/exactlocation')
def exactlocation():
    return render_template('stuff.html#exactlocation')
```

How do I link to a specific location in a template?

Comment: That's browser behavior. Just render your template normally and the browser will take care of it (assuming you have the named anchor on the page).

Comment: @dirn I'm not sure what you mean. If I use return render_template('stuff.html') how does the browser know to go to a specific location on the page rather than the top, run javascript check on page load?

Comment: Browsers will jump to named anchors automatically, no JavaScript needed. The only requirement is that the named anchor (i.e., `<a name="exactlocation"></a>`) exists in the HTML.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to dirn's comments I managed to get this working with the code below.

Pass the `_anchor` keyword to `url_for` to append an anchor to the generated URL.

nav menu:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('.stuff', _anchor='exactlocation') }}">Go to specific id on suff page</a>
```

Flask route:

```
@main.route('/')
def stuff():
    return render_template('stuff.html')
```

`stuff.html`:

```html
...
<section id="exactlocation">
...
```

Comment: This also works dynamically, as in:

`<a href=" {{ url_for('comments', _anchor=comment.id) }}">`