# Is there a way to go to a specific part of html page with flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am creating a single webpage and I would like to go to a specific section (in this case called results) of that page using Flask's render_template.

Is there any way to do so, for example by passing in an argument go_to_results = True into render_template:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return render_template('index.html')

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            return render_template('index.html')

        prediction = predict(file, 3, percentage=True)

        return render_template('index.html', prediction_html = prediction, go_to_results = True)
        
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I found this example but it doesn't fit my needs, as I am using only 1 HTML page ('index.html'). [Link to a specific location in a Flask template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843675/link-to-a-specific-location-in-a-flask-template).

UPDATE WORKING SOLUTION:
I added this to the HTML results section:

```
<a href="#results">
</a>
```

And then I used this JS code.

```
<script>
    function jumpToHash(hash){
        if (hash){
            var url = location.href;
            location.href = "#results";
        }
    }
jumpToHash({{ anchor }});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a little bit of JS to your template and pass the anchor.

In your Flask:

```
render_template('index.html', anchor="your_tag_id")
```

JS code to add to `index.html`:

```html
<script>
    function jump(h){
        var url = location.href;               //Save down the URL without hash.
        location.href = "#"+h;                 //Go to the target element.
        history.replaceState(null,null,url);   //Don't like hashes. Changing it back.
    }

    jump({{ anchor }});
</script>
```

Credit for the JS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript).

Comment: Thanks Luca, your explanation is very clear though it doesn't seem to work. I have 0 knowledge of JS unfortunately.
Would I need to change something inside the JS function jump?
Or could it be due to the other JS code inside the html file (too big to paste here):

Comment: Hatd to say.... as a precaution, move the js to the bottom of the HTML

Comment: I tried to do so, didnt work unfortunately. I also commented out all the other JS code, but still it did not work. I also hard-coded "results" instead of {{ anchor }}, that did not work either...

Comment: Are you sure your results div has the `id="results"` ? Would you be able to try the other solutions proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript ?

Comment: I am sure, thanks though. I also tried the other solutions and I tried resetting the Flask application etc. I will now get some debugging help elsewhere, will let you know the outcome.

Comment: I added the solution in the question.

Comment: Ok, good. Looks like my solution worked.