# Adobe Edge Animation in Muse: Scroll to an anchor by clicking on the animation

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe-edge, muse

I created some Rollover Buttons in Adobe Edge Animate. I placed them in Adobe Muse. The Rollover works with mouseover and mouseout very good. But I want to click also on the animation and that it scrolls smooth to an anchor. 
I don't want that it jumps to the anchor without smooth scrolling.

Can someone here help me getting a code for this? My anchors are named: aboutme, contact

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you did

Comment: The website isn't published yet. What do you need to see? Will take some screenshots then.

Comment: Well, I don't have a code. But this site has something that I need but I don't know what I have to do with these things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: window.open("../../index.html#aboutme", "_parent"); BUT that just jumps to the anchor and doesn't scroll smooth. And I also need a way that I don't have to put the full URL into it, just the anchor aboutme