# How to scroll to an internal anchor link accounting for a sticky top bar?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, visibility, sticky

I'm using Foundation, and would like a sticky top bar with sub links to internal parts of the page. The problem is, if I do it naïvely, i.e.:

```
<div class="sticky">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#/intro">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/basic">Basic</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>

... not much stuff ...

<a name="/intro"></a>
<h2>Intro</h2>

... much stuff ...

<a name="/basic"></a>
<h2>Basic</h2>

... much stuff ...
```

... then the top of the page scrolls to the top of the header, which is then obscured by the sticky top bar. [See the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/398/) and click on the top links to see what I mean.

How can I keep a sticky top bar, yet have clicks on the top bar scroll the page such that the header is right below the top bar, instead of obscured?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**

Add an `<h2>` style rule to the CSS, something like:

```
h2 {
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**Solution #2**

If you want to minimise the extra white-space added to the document, you might try something like the following, instead:

```
a[name]:target {
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

This will only add white-space to the `<a>` element which is currently targeted.

Comment: Thanks. This works with `padding-top`, but leaves a lot of unnecessary space. There must be a better way ...

Comment: I have added an alternative solution to the post above, which will result in less whitespace being added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a function to do this.

1. It changes the window location, so acts as if the user clicked an `<a href='#internal-ref></a>` link.
2. It scrolls to the link anyway using [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript) for making me aware of its existence).
3. It then scrolls back by `$("nav.top-bar").height()` pixels using [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

**The code**:

```
function scrollToAnchor(name) {
  // change location
  window.location = '#' + name;

  // scroll to element anyway
  var element = $("a[name='" + name + "']")[0];
  if (!element) {
    console.error("No such anchor with name", name);
    return;
  }
  element.scrollIntoView();

  // scroll back to leave room for sticky nav
  var stickyNavHeight = $("nav.top-bar").height();
  console.log(stickyNavHeight);
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - stickyNavHeight);
}
```

**[Live demo](http://csaftoiu.github.io/foundation-range-slider-angular/)**.