# Scrolling to an ID when a form is submitted?

Tags: jquery

I am hoping someone can help me out. I am using a form script called Machform. The problem I am having is when my form is halfway down a page and a user submits the form they are automatically sent to the top of the page and therefore have to scroll back down to the form to see if there are any errors or if a success message is shown verifying the form was sent successfully.

The form itself is wrapped in a div with an ID (#mf_placeholder). I have been searching for a way to have the page scroll to this ID when the submit button is clicked but I know nothing about jquery or javascript. I have came across some things that sounded promising such as [Smoothly scroll to an element without a jQuery plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/) (which I cannot get to work due to my lack of knowledge on how to implement the code) and by trying to replace:

```
onload="javascript:parent.scrollTo(0,0);"
```

**with:**

```
onload="javascript:this.scrollIntoView();"
```

within the js file.

If I "**remove**" the first line of code above then clicking on the submit button makes the window stay exactly where it is when I click the submit button resulting in having to scroll up a bit to see the success or error message.

If I "**replace**" the first line of code above with the second line of code above then it gives me the desired result however it will not work because when you visit the page it automatically scrolls down to the form.

The js is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var mf_iframe_height;
var mf_iframe_padding_bottom = 0;

if($("#mf_placeholder").data("formheight") !== undefined){
  __machform_height = $("#mf_placeholder").data("formheight");
}

if($("#mf_placeholder").data("formurl") !== undefined){
  __machform_url = $("#mf_placeholder").data("formurl");
}

if($("#mf_placeholder").data("paddingbottom") !== undefined){
  var mf_iframe_padding_bottom = $("#mf_placeholder").data("paddingbottom");
}

var mf_iframe = $('<iframe id="mf_iframe" onload="javascript:parent.scrollTo(0,0);" height="' + __machform_height + '" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none" src="'+ __machform_url +'"><a href="'+ __machform_url +'">View Form</a></iframe>');
$("#mf_placeholder").after(mf_iframe);
$("#mf_placeholder").remove();

$.receiveMessage(function(e){      
  if(e.data.indexOf('run_safari_cookie_fix') != -1){
    //execute safari cookie fix
    var mf_folder = __machform_url.substring(0,__machform_url.lastIndexOf('/'));

    window.location.href = mf_folder + '/safari_init.php?ref=' + window.btoa(window.location.href);
    return;
  }else{
    //adjust the height of the iframe     
    var new_height = Number( e.data.replace( /.*mf_iframe_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ) );
    if (!isNaN(new_height) && new_height > 0 && new_height !== mf_iframe_height) {
      new_height += mf_iframe_padding_bottom; //add padding bottom

      //height has changed, update the iframe
      mf_iframe.height(mf_iframe_height = new_height);

      //just to make sure the height is being applied 
      document.getElementById("mf_iframe").setAttribute('style','width:100%;border:none;height:' + new_height + 'px !important');
    }
  }

});
```

});

(I'm not sure why the last }); will not display within the code box)

To embed the form I am using this code:

```
<div id="mf_placeholder" data-formurl="xxx/forms/embed.php?id=10118" data-formheight="705" data-paddingbottom="10">
```

The code above also includes some script tags after the end of the div tag to include the js file above as well as a couple of others which will not display here for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work? Ideally I'd really like to have the animated "scroll to" effect if possible as it is really slick. Please remember I know nothing about javascript unfortunately so I appreciate any help you can give me.

Thank you!

Comment: simple anchor in the url?

Comment: Simple anchor means: adding '#youridname' to the url you're submitting to (right, @zipzit?).

Comment: I cannot add an anchor tag. This is a form script with an administrative backend which allows loads of forms created very easily. Each form has a built in success message which will automatically take the place of the form on the page when it is submitted. You can also create mutli page forms where the "submit" button turns into a "continue" button so I don't think it's as easy as adding an anchor. I am familiar with html and css. Javascript is completely greek to me.

Comment: Wow, for what those guys are charging, the system should work much better than that.  I think you want to use the anchor tag `#mf_placeholder`  I can't believe they'd list it, without intending its use.  I will say, best place to raise this question is not here at stackoverflow, but instead at the [Machform discussion forum](http://www.appnitro.com/forums/)

Comment: Note: you could paste page location stuff into cookies, but that is a major pain.  The anchor should work much easier.  In the alternative, you can use a more traditional webform submit and validation system.  Cheaper, easier to use.  Something like http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have contacted them but have not heard back yet. Yes I do want to use the `#mf_placeholder`. I was hoping it would be something as simple as using something like `onload="javascript:parent.scrollTo(#mf_placeholder);` but that didn't work. Researching for the last 4 hours and trial and error without success has brought me here for help!

Comment: Hard to say exactly what will work, without seeing ALL of your code.  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Yes I have come across that page in my search. Unfortunately part of my problem is I do not know how to implement any javascript correctly. For example, on the page I linked to in my first post [link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/) Its only a couple of lines of code but I would not know how to input it into my js file.