# Changing onload to point to an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to change this code to target a div with an ID?

```
onload="javascript:parent.scrollTo(0,0);"
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. This is related to my question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367012/scrolling-to-an-id-when-a-form-is-submitted) but I can't reply to that to get any help.

Edit: My apologies. I am new to Stack Overflow and in my other post I give a lot of information. When I wanted to update it with more information/questions because I have been spending hours and hours trying to figure this out, I could not as it does not give me the option. So yes it is "related" to my other question however there are no replies for me to add more information. I guess I am not allowed to post any updated information or questions.

Comment: Please, for god's sake, don't put `javascript:` in `onload`!

Comment: This is not my code. I am using a form script and trying to get it to do what I want (actually what it should be doing anyways). I know nothing about javascript. You can see my link to my issue if you want an explanation. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Not sure why don't you use: `onload="document.getElementById('myDIV').scrollIntoView();"` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling to an ID when a form is submitted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367012/scrolling-to-an-id-when-a-form-is-submitted)

Comment: Boy was I excited to try this. Unfortunately it made my form disappear when I changed `onload="javascript:parent.scrollTo(0,0);"` to `onload="document.getElementById('#mf_placeholder').scrollIntoView();"`. I am dealing with a form script with lots of files (not written by me) and I have contacted the devs but have not heard a response so i am attempting to try and figure it out. Thank you for your reply A Wolff

Comment: @Snorlax - Is it considered a duplicate? My other post that you linked to doesn't give me an option to update it with other information or questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
function scrollTo(element) {
    location.hash = element;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/43j177x9/1

Call it like this:

```
scrollTo("element");
```

That will cause it to scroll down to your `<div id="element"></div>` element.

In your case, it should be:

```
onload="scrollTo('element');"
```

Alternatively you can use `document.getElementById('element').scrollIntoView();` (thanks to [Derek 朕會功夫](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283863/derek-%e6%9c%95%e6%9c%83%e5%8a%9f%e5%a4%ab)).

Comment: Thanks for your input Snorlax but then this automatically scrolls to the ID on page load. I am seeing this is a lot more complicated than what I thought it was going to be. The script I am using has the code I pasted above in it but somehow the code must be triggered or something. My link I gave gives a lot more detail. I appreciate your attempt at helping me though.

Comment: @Maquar I simply answered your question based on your code. If my answer has not solved your problem, you should update your post with some more information.

Comment: There's actually a native function for that `.scrollIntoView`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You are absolutely correct. I did not know about that. I have updated my post.

Comment: @Snorlax You certainly did Snorlax and my apologies. I am new to Stack Overflow so i didn't want to repost my entire other thread which is located at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367012/scrolling-to-an-id-when-a-form-is-submitted)