# Parallax navigation menu slow effect

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am creating a parallax webpage, my navigation menu bar is working well, but it does not contain slow motion (Like slowly going up or down page). 
Is there anyway I can fix this problem? It was working for a while and it just disappeared.

Here is my code:

```css
#fp-nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 52;
 top: 50%;
 right: 15px;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -ms-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 -o-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
 transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#fp-nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#fp-nav ul li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li.active a {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: solid 2px #000;
}

.color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li a {
 background color: #000;
}

#fp-nav ul li.active a {
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 margin-left: -1px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 -o-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
 transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
  background color: #000;
}

.color-weight-light#fp-nav ul li .nav-title {
 color: #000;
}

.nav-title {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "proxima-nova";
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: -11px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
    -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
    -ms-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
    -o-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
    line-height: 32px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

li:hover .nav-title {
opacity:1;
}

li a{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-one" data-url-id="home-block-one">
  <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
</div>

<div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-two" data-url-id="home-block-two">
    <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
</div>

<div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-three" data-url-id="home-block-three">
    <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
</div>

<div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-four" data-url-id="home-block-four">
    <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
</div>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// fade in #back-top
 $(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#back-top').fadeIn();
   } else {
    $('#back-top').fadeOut();
   }
  });

  // scroll body to 0px on click
  $('#back-top a').click(function () {
   $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
   }, 800);
   return false;
  });
 });

});
</script>


<div id="fp-nav" style="margin-top: -46px;" class="color-weight-light">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#top">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Home</span>
   </a>

   </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#content">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Slim Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-one">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Blogs</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-two">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Heatlh Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-three">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Video</span>
   </a>
  </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#home-block-four">
   <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="nav-title">Skin Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I wonder if this is what you are trying to do: http://www.jarallax.com/demo3/

Comment: yes it is! But I want to put this effect when the people click the side menu bar (which is circles)

Comment: The links at the top are the same as your side menu. you just need to use CSS to move them to the side.

Comment: it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor using jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript) and whoever else helped with this post

https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/nsff4wb6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DDIndex</title>
    <style>
        #fp-nav {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 52;
            top: 50%;
            right: 15px;
            padding: 0 10px 0 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
            -ms-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
            -o-transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
            transition: opacity .3s 0s linear;
            transform: translatez(0);
            -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

            #fp-nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

                #fp-nav ul li {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

        .color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li.active a {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: solid 2px #000;
        }

        .color-weight-light #fp-nav ul li a {
            background color: #000;
        }

        #fp-nav ul li.active a {
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            margin-left: -1px;
        }

        #fp-nav ul li a {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            -webkit-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
            -moz-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
            -ms-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
            -o-transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
            transition: background color .1s linear,border color .1s linear;
            background color: #000;
        }

        .color-weight-light#fp-nav ul li .nav-title {
            color: #000;
        }

        .nav-title {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            opacity: 0;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-family: "proxima-nova";
            letter-spacing: .1em;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: -11px;
            padding: 0 0 5px 0;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            -ms-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            -o-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            line-height: 32px;
            /*took out hidden*/
            /*visibility: hidden;*/
        }

        li:hover .nav-title {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        li a {
            position: relative;
        }

        /*added*/
        .parallax-block {
            min-height: 400px;
            background: transparent;
            width: 70%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/2.1.3/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax-block" id="top" data-url-id="top">
        <p>HomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHomeHome</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-block" id="content" data-url-id="content">
        <p>Slim ProductsSlim ProductsSlim ProductsSlim ProductsSlim ProductsSlim ProductsSlim Products</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>

    </div>
    <div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-one" data-url-id="home-block-one">
        <p>BlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogsBlogs</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>

    </div>

    <div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-two" data-url-id="home-block-two">
        <p>Heatlh ProductsHeatlh ProductsHeatlh ProductsHeatlh ProductsHeatlh ProductsHeatlh Products</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>

    </div>

    <div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-three" data-url-id="home-block-three">
        <p>VideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideoVideo</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>

    </div>

    <div class="parallax-block" id="home-block-four" data-url-id="home-block-four">
        <p>Skin ProductsSkin ProductsSkin ProductsSkin ProductsSkin ProductsSkin ProductsSkin Products</p>
        <p>La enfrente baterias director en amarillo mezquino no. Haber con nadie julio apago iba han armas oro. Se me al hombre delito mareos. Suya paro celo no sepa si seda masa. Del aborrecia ese impresion restantes etc vestibulo servicios. Fue molestarle mia actualidad los misteriosa pre. Testigos oro mediante eso amarillo facundia conviene. Volverse una victimas tio reaccion dictador paz cuestion. Impregnado rio dos secretario tan dio satisfecha. </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#fp-nav a").click(function (e) {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');

                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $(href).offset().top
                }, 800);

                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>

    <div id="fp-nav" style="margin-top: -46px;" class="color-weight-light">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#top">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Home</span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#content">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Slim Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home-block-one">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Blogs</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home-block-two">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Heatlh Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home-block-three">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Video</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home-block-four">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="nav-title">Skin Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```