# Zoom on particular location on web page when load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making a web page for mobile as a web view on that page i am showing a multiple coupons image as check boxes this is my code:

```
<style>
    .bordered{
        border: 5px solid green;
    }
</style>
```

This is my html

```
<div class="row ">
    <?php foreach ($results as $result):?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-centered piege">
        <input type="checkbox" id="piega1" class="piege servizioSection2 " name="imgSection2"value="Piega By Wella Professionals" style="opacity: 0;">
        <label  class="piega labelStylingImg " for="piega1">
            <img height="100" width="100" src="<?php echo $result['coupanImages'];?>" id="<?php echo $result['t_flyercoupan_id'];?>" for="piega1" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega ">
        </label>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

This is my script
    assets/js/jquery.min.js">

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.immaginePiega').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass('bordered');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

user click on any image and its add into the add to cart when user see that coupon he selected on cart and click on it the flyer page will open and zoom on the coupon he add in the cart.
Any suggestion how its going to be done or library i have to study?

Comment: A little hard to tell what you want, but sounds like you just need a basic anchor `<a id='anchorid'>` and a `#anchorid` in the url.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597811/2181514

Comment: Tip:  You might like to remove the 'or a library' part of your question as that makes it offtopic for SO.  Please read the [tour],  [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic