# My JS scrollTo function does not scroll the page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

My goal is to have a clickable button/link to scroll to a certain position in a page. I have referenced from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor) by **Michael Whinfrey**, the code works perfectly on fiddle but not on mine.

This may be a bit messy but I have multiple GridViews in a table, and some **td** has **div** and some don't. Also in the code behind I have the following code in Page_load.

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;
```

Below is my aspx page simplified.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollTo(name) {
            ScrollToResolver(document.getElementById(name));
        }
        function ScrollToResolver(elem) {
            var jump = parseInt(elem.getBoundingClientRect().top * .2);
            document.body.scrollTop += jump;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop += jump;
            if (!elem.lastjump || elem.lastjump > Math.abs(jump)) {
                elem.lastjump = Math.abs(jump);
                setTimeout(function () { ScrollToResolver(elem); }, "100");
            } else {
                elem.lastjump = null;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  .......some input/textbox......
  <button onclick="scrollTo('divDesignation')">TEST</button>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:GridView id="gv1" .....>
      ......the whole table has 6~7 rows of GridView data that is not displaying here.....
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="divDesignation" runat="server" style="max-height:600px; overflow-y:auto;">
            <asp:GridView id="gvDesignation" ......
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to scroll to the divDesignation  when click the button but it simply will not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens in your version? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see any error in the console.