# open a webpage with button clicked

Tags: html

I'm writing a code in HTML and it has 2 buttons, say `a` and `b`. I want to pass something in my URL that will trigger the button. I know how we do it for div.

```html
<div class="a">
  <a name="a" /> This is Div A
</div>
<div class="b">
  <a name="b" /> This is Div B
</div>
```

and I can directly pass `myURL.com#a`/`myURL.com/#b`, to go to that div. But I want to know if I can do it using buttons.

Thanks

Comment: so you want buttons to go to the `divs` ? or what exactly. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with some javascript like:

```
<button onclick="window.location='#a';">Go to Div A</button>
```

Comment: remember to change class="a" to id="a" in your DIV

Answer (score 0):

If you want either button A **OR** button B to be visable you can use this:

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: none;
    }
.button:target {
    display: block
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- link in the same page -->
<a href="#A">go to button 1</a><br>
<a href="#B">go to button 2</a><br>

<!-- link from external page -->
<a href="your_url.com/#A">go to button A</a><br>
<a href="your_url.com/#B">go to button B</a><br>

<!-- buttons will only be visable when linked to -->
<a class="button" id="A"><input type="button" value="button A"></a>
<a class="button" id="B"><input type="button" value="button B"></a>
```

If you just want to jump to the button you answered your own question.
Just wrap the `<div id="A">` around the button.

Answer (score -1):

First add the `id` attribute to the div. Eg; `<div class="b" id="part-b">`
Then just link to `mypage.html#part-b`, eg; `<a href="mypage.html#part-b>Go to part b</a>`

Comment: "But I want to know if I can do it using buttons". You are using <a>