# Scroll to the particular div by Clicking on the div on any Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been answered but the scenario of my question is quite different, so I will try to explain it. If anyone wants more explanation I would love to give it.

I have a filter bar that consists of 8 boxes.

```
 <div class="filter-box  filter-box--green px-2 pt-3 pb-4" data-box-id="web-dev">
     <img width="60" height="60" src="{!! asset('images/Service-page/Web Development-hover.svg') !!}" alt="Web Dev" />
         <div class="title text-center mt-2 pb-4">
                            Web<br />Development
         </div>

         <div class="arrow">
             <img src="{!! asset('images/Service-page/Green.svg') !!}">
         </div>
  </div>
```

When I am clicking on the box, it scrolls to the specific div based on the `data-box-id`

Below is the JavaScript code that scrolls to the particular div.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.filter-box').on('click', function(e) {
            // console.log(window.scroll)
            var boxId = $(this).attr('data-box-id');

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + boxId).offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here I used `offset`. The problem is that sometimes, the cursor is not at target. What I want to achieve is that when I click anywhere on the filter box, it should scroll and my cursor position should be on the expected div.

Comment: would you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor and hopefully that will help you

Comment: its one another the same locaion.hash or animate

Comment: so you want a smooth scroll effect when jumping to an anchor?

Comment: well animate is doind that job i want to hit the exact div

Comment: @Max90 its is i have achieve that

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery .animate to have a smooth scroll to the desired element see the example.

```js
$( "#notelement" ).click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($('#element').offset().top)
  },500);
});
```

```css
#notelement{
  margin-bottom:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notelement">Other element</div>
<div id="element">Scroll to element</div>
```