# How to scroll a React page when it loads?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to pass a value as the hash in the url (myapp.com#somevalue) and have the page scroll to that item when the page loads - exactly the behavior of using a hash fragment since the beginning of the internet. I tried using scrollIntoView but that fails on iOS. Then I tried just unsetting/setting window.location.hash but there seems to be a race condition. It only works when the delay is more than 600ms.

I would like a more solid solution and don't want to introduce an unnecessary delay. When the delay is too short, it appears to scroll to the desired item but then scrolls to the top of the page. You won't see the effect on this demo but it happens in my actual app https://codesandbox.io/s/pjok544nrx line 75

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;

    let updateSearchControl = hash => {
      let selectedOption = self.state.searchOptions.filter(
        option => option.value === hash
      )[0];
      if (selectedOption) {
        // this doesn't work with Safari on iOS
        // document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView(true);

        // this works if delay is 900 but not 500 ms
        setTimeout(() => {
          // unset and set the hash to trigger scrolling to target
          window.location.hash = null;
          window.location.hash = hash;
          // scroll back by the height of the Search box
          window.scrollBy(
            0,
            -document.getElementsByClassName("heading")[0].clientHeight
          );
        }, 900);
      } else if (hash) {
        this.searchRef.current.select.focus();
      }
    };

    // Get the hash
    // I want this to work as a Google Apps Script too which runs in
    // an iframe and has a special way to get the hash
    if (!!window["google"]) {
      let updateHash = location => {
        updateSearchControl(location.hash);
      };
      eval("google.script.url.getLocation(updateHash)");
    } else {
      let hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
      updateSearchControl(hash);
    }
  }
```

EDIT: I tracked down the line of React that re-renders the page and consequently resets the scroll position after it already scrolled where I told it to go in componentDidMount(). It's [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/21d5f7d32d5becf5c8e986ff0202059be643dc15/packages/react-dom/src/shared/CSSPropertyOperations.js#L82).
`style[styleName] = styleValue;` At the time the page is re-rendered it is setting the width style property of the inputbox component of the react-select box component. The stack trace right before it does this looks like

```
(anonymous) @   VM38319:1
setValueForStyles   @   react-dom.development.js:6426
updateDOMProperties @   react-dom.development.js:7587
updateProperties    @   react-dom.development.js:7953
commitUpdate    @   react-dom.development.js:8797
commitWork  @   react-dom.development.js:17915
commitAllHostEffects    @   react-dom.development.js:18634
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:199
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:256
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:18867
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:20372
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:255
completeRoot    @   react-dom.development.js:20371
performWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:20300
performWork @   react-dom.development.js:20208
performSyncWork @   react-dom.development.js:20182
requestWork @   react-dom.development.js:20051
scheduleWork    @   react-dom.development.js:19865
scheduleRootUpdate  @   react-dom.development.js:20526
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @   react-dom.development.js:20554
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:20611
ReactRoot.render    @   react-dom.development.js:20907
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:21044
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:20413
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:21040
render  @   react-dom.development.js:21109
(anonymous) @   questionsPageIndex.jsx:10
./src/client/questionsPageIndex.jsx @   index.html:673
__webpack_require__ @   index.html:32
(anonymous) @   index.html:96
(anonymous) @   index.html:99
```

I don't know where to move my instruction to scroll the page. It has to happen after these styles are set which is happening after componentDidMount().

EDIT: I need to better clarify exactly what I need this to do. Apologies for not doing that before.

#### Must haves

This has to work on all common desktop and mobile devices.

When the page loads there could be three situations depending on what query is provided in the url after the #:

- 1) no query was provided - nothing happens
- 2) a valid query was provided - the page scrolls instantly to the desired anchor and the page's title changes to the label of the option
- 3) an invalid query was provided - the query is entered into the search box, the search box is focused and the menu opens with options limited by the provided query as if they had been typed in. The cursor is located in the search box at the end of the query so the user can modify the query.

A valid query is one that matches the value of one of the options. An invalid query is one that doesn't.

The browser back and forward buttons should move the scroll position accordingly.

Any time an option is chosen from the Search box the page should scroll instantly to that anchor, the query should clear returning to the placeholder "Search...", the url should update, and the document's title should change to the option's label.

#### Optional but would be great

After making a selection the menu closes and the query goes back to "Search...", and either

- the Search box retains the focus so the user can begin typing another query. The next time it is **clicked**, the menu opens, and the Searchbox query from before the selection, the menu's filter and the menu scroll position are restored (most preferred), or
- the Search box loses focus. The next time it is **focused**, the menu opens, and the Search box query from before the selection, the menu's filter and the menu scroll position are restored (preferred), or
- the Search box retains the focus so the user can begin typing another query. The prior query and menu scroll position are lost.

Comment: possible solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor

Comment: maybe useEffect is worth to give it a try. as I understand useEffect will run after rendering submitted to the screen and at that time the element is ready to scroll to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this right after the imports in my component's file:

```
let initialValidSlug = '';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  window.location.hash = '';
  window.location.hash = (initialValidSlug ? initialValidSlug : '');
  window.scrollBy(0, -document.getElementsByClassName("heading")[0].clientHeight);
  console.log('window.addEventListener')
});
```

and have this for my `componentDidMount()`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { pathname, isValid } = this.state;
    if(!isValid && pathname) {               // if there's a pathname but it's invalid,
      this.searchRef.current.select.focus(); // focus on the search bar
    }
    initialValidSlug = pathname;  // sets the value to be used in the $.ready() above
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to do this with the `react-scrollable-anchor` library:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ScrollableAnchor from "react-scrollable-anchor";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 7000 }}>nothing to see here</div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 7000 }}>never mind me</div>
        <ScrollableAnchor id={"doge"}>
          <div>bork</div>
        </ScrollableAnchor>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can see it working by going here: https://zwoj0xw503.codesandbox.io/#doge

Comment: Internally, ScrollableAnchors effects the scrolling by setting window.location.hash, so it has the same answer to the What question and doesn't answer the When question. If this is indeed a matter for TC39 as it seems, and given that I didn't immediately receive any instant answers that capturing the "ready to be scrolled event" is impossible, I must be violating a basic principal of web design on my first project, but that is really hard to accept. This seems like an eminently reasonable requirement. https://github.com/gabergg/react-scrollable-anchor/blob/master/src/utils/hash.js#L5-L11

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using `react-router-dom`'s [HashRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md) with React's `ref.current.scrollIntoView()` or `window.scrollTo(ref.currrent.offsetTop)`.

Currently tested and working on Chrome (desktop/android), Firefox(desktop), Silk Browser(android), Saumsung Internet(android), and Safari(iOS -- with one caveat in that it instantly jumps to the selection). While I was able to test and confirm it's working within the sandbox environment's `iframe`, you'll have to adapt/test it within a standalone `iframe`.

I'd also like to point out that your approach is very `jQuery` like and that you should avoid directly attempting to utilize or manipulate the `DOM` and/or the `window`. In addition, you seem to use a lot of `let` variables throughout your code, but they remain unchanged. Instead, they should be a `const` variable as React evaluates variables each time it re-renders, so unless you plan on changing that variable during the re-render process, there's no need to use `let`.

**Working example**: https://v6y5211n4l.codesandbox.io

[image: Edit ScrollIntoView on Selection]

---

**components/ScrollBar**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import Select from "react-select";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const scrollOpts = {
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "start"
};

class ScrollBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const titleRefs = props.searchOptions.map(
      ({ label }) => (this[label] = React.createRef())
    ); // map over options and use "label" as a ref name; ex: this.orange
    this.topWindow = React.createRef();
    this.searchRef = React.createRef();
    const pathname = props.history.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, ""); // set current pathname without the "/"

    this.state = {
      titleRefs,
      menuIsOpen: false,
      isValid: props.searchOptions.some(({ label }) => label === pathname), // check if the current pathname matches any of the labels
      pathname
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { pathname, isValid } = this.state;
    if (isValid) this.scrollToElement(); // if theres a pathname and it matches a label, scroll to it
    if (!isValid && pathname) this.searchRef.current.select.focus(); // if there's a pathname but it's invalid, focus on the search bar
  }

  // allows us to update state based upon prop updates (in this case
  // we're looking for changes in the history.location.pathname)
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const nextPath = props.history.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, "");
    const isValid = props.searchOptions.some(({ label }) => label === nextPath);
    return state.pathname !== nextPath ? { pathname: nextPath, isValid } : null; // if the path has changed, update the pathname and whether or not it is valid
  }

  // allows us to compare new state to old state (in this case
  // we're looking for changes in the pathname)
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.pathname !== prevState.pathname) {
      this.scrollToElement();
    }
  }

  scrollToElement = () => {
    const { isValid, pathname } = this.state;
    const elem = isValid ? pathname : "topWindow";
    setTimeout(() => {
     window.scrollTo({
        behavior: "smooth",
        top: this[elem].current.offsetTop - 45
      });
    }, 100);
  };

  onInputChange = (options, { action }) => {
    if (action === "menu-close") {
      this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false }, () =>
        this.searchRef.current.select.blur()
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
    }
  };

  onChange = ({ value }) => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    if (history.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, "") !== value) { // if the select value is different than the previous selected value, update the url -- required, otherwise, react-router will complain about pushing the same pathname/value that is current in the url
      history.push(value);
    }
    this.searchRef.current.select.blur();
  };

  onFocus = () => this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });

  render() {
    const { pathname, menuIsOpen, titleRefs } = this.state;
    const { searchOptions, styles } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Helmet title={this.state.pathname || "Select an option"} />
        <div className="heading">
          <Select
            placeholder="Search..."
            isClearable={true}
            isSearchable={true}
            options={searchOptions}
            defaultInputValue={pathname}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
            ref={this.searchRef}
            value={null}
            styles={styles || {}}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="fruits-list">
          <div ref={this.topWindow} />
          {searchOptions.map(({ label, value }, key) => (
            <div key={value} id={value}>
              <p ref={titleRefs[key]}>{label}</p>
              {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14].map(num => (
                <p key={num}>{num}</p>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ScrollBar.propTypes = {
  searchOptions: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired,
  styles: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func)
};

export default withRouter(ScrollBar);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import ScrollBar from "../src/components/ScrollBar";

const config = {
  htmlAttributes: { lang: "en" },
  title: "My App",
  titleTemplate: "Scroll Search - %s",
  meta: [
    {
      name: "description",
      content: "The best app in the world."
    }
  ]
};

const searchOptions = [
  {
    label: "apple",
    value: "apple"
  },
  {
    label: "orange",
    value: "orange"
  },
  {
    label: "banana",
    value: "banana"
  },
  {
    label: "strawberry",
    value: "strawberry"
  }
];

const styles = {
  menu: base => ({ ...base, width: "100%", height: "75vh" }),
  menuList: base => ({ ...base, minHeight: "75vh" }),
  option: base => ({ ...base, color: "blue" })
};

const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Helmet {...config} />
    <ScrollBar searchOptions={searchOptions} styles={styles} />
  </HashRouter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. It handles well the case when a valid value is provided but I also want to handle when an invalid one is. I clarified the details above and started work on a modification of your solution here https://codesandbox.io/s/xl46pnmr8p

Comment: Updated answer above. Also, the `setTimeout` is required for mobile browsers. Otherwise, it won't scroll.

Comment: Just finished. It works on my computer but it doesn't work in Safari on my iPhone. It will scroll to the correct spot on load but the Search box disappears. If you manually swipe all the way back up, and then swipe one more time, the box comes back. The Search box stays put if you manually scroll but scrollIntoView() does not work on this device. Please try this on mobile: https://v6y5211n4l.codesandbox.io/#/orange

Comment: Updated answer. That's a problem with mobile not liking `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` and `position: absolute;` on the `Select` component. Instead, set `.heading` as `position: fixed; width: 100%;` and remove the `overflow: hidden;`. As such, you'll have to use an `window.scrollTo()` with an `offsetTop` calculation, which will scroll to the correct location (since a fixed position floats above, you'll have to offset it, otherwise it'll land directly on top of the `ref`). In addition, another drawback is that when using the `back` button it immediately jumps to the last selected location.

Comment: No matter which direction you take, `ref.scrollIntoView()` or `window.scrollTo()` you're going to run into browser limitations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/element.scrollintoviewifneeded-polyfill.

As soon as possibile in your application import the library

```
import 'element.scrollintoviewifneeded-polyfill';
```

Than you can use the method `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();` on all the dom nodes.
The library will polyfill the method so you could use this on all browsers.

I recommend you to use this with a `react ref` so you don't have to call getElementById or other document method in order to retrieve the dom node.

```
const ref = React.createRef();
<div id="somevalue" ref={ref} />
```

Than in your `componentDidMount` you can use the same method you describe for retrieving the id of the div you want to scroll in, get the associated ref and call

```
    ref.current.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
```

Where the ref is the right div reference, you can obviously store all the ref in a map and than retrieve in your components methods.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is still doing it. It jumps to the right place, then jumps back to the top. https://github.com/dancancro/questions/blob/nodiv/src/client/components/questions-page.jsx#L100-L101