# How can I redirect a page internally in html once?

Tags: html, meta

I'm trying to create a menu and some sections but when the site loads I want to hide the menu. I want to do this with a redirect to the first section. I know this can be done in java script but its not allowed.

I have used the refresh meta tag but its giving me a seizure from it looping. I've change "0" out with other numbers but the same thing happens. There is also enough to scroll to hide the menu.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=#home" />
 <nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
 </nav>
<section id="home">
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</section>
```

I need it to redirect to the first section hiding the menu.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this with a meta tag alone. Why is JavaScript not allowed?

Comment: Definitely cannot use meta refresh since it will just keep refreshing the page. If you want to access the page and scroll to #home then put #home at the end of the url or use js to scroll programmatically

Comment: @j08691 thanks for letting me know. I really wanted to avoid JavaScript if I could.

Comment: @AmirBll Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995#254995  and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327171/user-adding-excessive-bolding-in-otherwise-good-edits - that edit is NOT considered good.

Comment: @Huangism okay darn. I guess I should delete this post lol. Is there a simple JavaScript way where it does this with as little code possible? Another post?

Comment: @AdamWilcox lot of different ways to do this, you can checkout the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for your guidance.