# How do I "jump" to a specific part of the page without adding to the URL?

Tags: javascript, html

For demonstrations:
Let's say I had this:

```
<div id=top>
<p>Placeholder 1</p>
</div>
<div id=mid>
<p>Placeholder 2</p>
</div>
<div id=bottom>
<p>Placeholder 3</p>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#top">Jump to Top</a>
</div>
```

If I were to press "Jump to Top" it would do what I want it to do, jump to a specific area. But it would change the URL to [www.your-domain-whatever.com/page#top](http://www.your-domain-whatever.com/page#top). How could I get the same functionality but keep the URL as [www.your-domain-whatever.com/page](http://www.your-domain-whatever.com/page) instead of [www.your-domain-whatever.com/page#top](http://www.your-domain-whatever.com/page#top)?
I've looked around, can't seem to find something that helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor)

Comment: (the accepted answer is maybe not the one you want there, however?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.scrollIntoView()`

```
var element = document.getElementById("top");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

The documentation for it is found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).