# How to create links to sections within your webpage using Framework7

Tags: html, scroll, hyperlink, html-framework-7

I am familiar with the classic method of linking to sections on your webpage, whereby the anchor tag is made to point to some elements id within the page, like this sample

```
<div class="main" id="section1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to jump to section 2.</p>
  <a href="#section2">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to jump to section 1.</p>
  <a href="#section1">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

But when I tried this trick within a Framework7 app, it didn't work. I guess it has to do with how Framework7 handles links and views, but I don't have any ideas on how to fix it. Please anyone with some experience or tips help me out.

Comment: Man Stack overflow is a wilderness

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that works on stack overflow a day later (see link below), however I didn't want to bother to answer my own question, but I've decided to do that now.

The solution lies with programmatically scrolling the desired element/section into view with JavaScript scrollIntoView method available on every DOM element.

In a Framework7 app, the scrollable container is the element with `.page-content` class, not the `html` or `body` tag. This was the cause of the shortcomings of the classic method which presupposes the scrollable container to be the `body` tag, unlike JavaScript scrollIntoView method which looks for the closest scrollable ancestor of the section.

```
document.querySelector(". section").scrollIntoView();
```

> Solution sourced from [Armando Pérez Marqués answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169950/13802903)

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving this was

```
var $$ = Dom7;

$$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
   // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // animate scroll effect
      $$('.page-content').scrollTop(
        $$(hash).offset().top-65, 
        800, 
        function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
            
        }
      )

    } // End if
});
```