# A javascript function that scroll down the page when user click's on a element

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

i wanted to creat a JS function that add's event listener to a link so when user click's on that link, it will scroll down the page to a spicific element
but for some reason it didn't work out so I need you'r help

i tried this code but it's not working

```
function scrollToElement(elementSelector, instance = 0) {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(elementSelector);
    if (elements.length > instance) {
      elements[instance].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }
  

const link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
const link2 = document.getElementById("link2");
const link3 = document.getElementById("link3");

link1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollToElement('.features');
});

link2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollToElement('.header', 1);
});

link3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollToElement('.column');
});
```

Comment: Why do you want a function and not a link?

Comment: [How to scroll an HTML page to a given anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-an-html-page-to-a-given-anchor)

Comment: Your code works as is with appropriate HTML: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLaprh9m/). You'll need to include your HTML to debug what's wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element is visible.

Try to change your function like following:

```
function scrollToElement(el, instance=0) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    if(!elements[instance].checkVisibility()) return;

    elements[instance].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
```